# Inserting to the mysql table in ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby, jruby

I have a table and a phonebook program that I get information from users and insert into the table , but because of I use two variable first and second for information of users I can't Insert them into the table. my code is below :

```
    def inserting
    first = gets
    second = gets
    @connect.query('INSERT INTO person VALUES(first,second)')
end
```

please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: could you change the tags for your questions ? what SQL client are you using?

Comment: I want to insert a record to the table in mysql . now why do I change the tag of my question?

Comment: Because you aren't using ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nor ruby-on-rails-3.1.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Rails, you should be using ActiveRecord. This is what helps you insert, update, and retrieve data from your tables.

What you should have is this:

```
def inserting
  first = gets
  second = gets

  Person.create(
    :first => first,
    :second => second
  )
end
```

Comment: but I use ruby not ruby on rails.

Comment: You should still use a DB connection library -- either ActiveRecord, DataMapper, or Sequel.

Comment: In this day and age, it's insane to use MySQL directly. There's too many risks in constructing the queries by hand to do that in a production environment. There are several good libraries that make interfacing easier, as [Marnen Laibow-Koser](http://stackoverflow.com/users/109011/marnen-laibow-koser) points out. I find that [sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) is the most flexible and doesn't require models, serving as a very good query generator at its core.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a prepared statement and parameter binding:

```
def inserting
    first  = gets
    second = gets
    stmt   = @connect.prepare('INSERT INTO person VALUES(?, ?)')
    stmt.execute(first, second)
    # Maybe some error checking would be a good idea too...
end
```

The docs are over here:

> http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql/2.8.1/frames

but they're, um, somewhat lacking in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a mysql error? The values probably aren't getting in there. Your query should probably be something more like this:

"INSERT INTO person VALUES('#{first},'#{second}')"

Not sanitized though..